# Understanding anonymous-functors and lambda

Tags: c++, lambda

Consider the following code:

```
#include <algorithm> 
#include <cstdlib> 
#include <iostream> 
#include <vector>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> srcVec; 
    for (int val = 0; val < 10; val++)
    { 
        srcVec.push_back(val); 
    }

    std::for_each(srcVec.begin(), srcVec.end(), [](int a){ std::cout << a << std::endl; }); 
}
```

**[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9b3f28e1e30fa231)**

I thought the `Function` type of the

```
template<class InputIterator, class Function>
Function for_each(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, Function f);
```

should necessary overload `operator ()`. But `N4296::5.1.2/3 [expr.prim.lambda]` does not require that.

> The closure type is declared in the smallest block scope, class scope,
>   or namespace scope that contains the corresponding lambda-expression.
>   An implementation may define the closure type differently from what is
>   described below provided this does not alter the observable behavior
>   of the program other than by changing:
>
> (3.1) — the size and/or alignment of the closure type,
>
> (3.2) — whether the closure type is trivially copyable (Clause 9),
>
> (3.3) — whether the  closure type is a standard-layout class (Clause
>   9), or
>
> (3.4) — whether the closure type is a POD class (Clause 9).

There was nothing said about the type should overload `operator ()`. So why should it?

Comment: This is covered later on in paragraph `5`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is covered in paragraph `5` (*emphasis mine*):

> The closure type for a non-generic lambda-expression **has a public inline function call operator (13.5.4)**
>   whose parameters and return type are described by the lambda-expression’s parameter-declaration-clause
>   and trailing-return-type respectively. For a generic lambda, the closure type has a public inline function call
>   operator member template (14.5.2) whose template-parameter-list consists of one invented type templateparameter
>   for each occurrence of auto in the lambda’s parameter-declaration-clause, in order of appearance.
>   The invented type template-parameter is a parameter pack if the corresponding parameter-declaration declares
>   a function parameter pack (8.3.5). The return type and function parameters of the function call
>   operator template are derived from the lambda-expression’s trailing-return-type and parameter-declarationclause
>   by replacing each occurrence of auto in the decl-specifiers of the parameter-declaration-clause with
>   the name of the corresponding invented template-parameter

and we can see in `13.5.4`:

> operator() shall be a non-static member function with an arbitrary number of parameters[...]